# cannot get download link from a web

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

I try to download all report from this site: https://www.opec.org/opec_web/en/publications/4814.htm
but I couldn't find the link automatically with beautiful soup and request. Could anyone help me?

I have tried below code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("https://www.opec.org/opec_web/static_files_project/media")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

links = []

for link in soup.findAll('a'):

    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be something like this

If it is a html document, you should use the 'html.parser', and you should link to the correct url in the request.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("https://www.opec.org/opec_web/en/publications/4814.htm")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

links = []

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if 'pdf' in href:
        print(href)
```